# variables in a for-loop

Tags: for-loop

when starting the for loop I would like to use values input by the user using this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double t,m,x,z,k,v,n ;

k = (1.38065*(pow (10,-23))); 

cout<< "input value a: " ;
cin >> m ;

cout<< "Input value b: " ;
cin >> t ;

cout<< "Input value c:" ;
cin >> x ;

cout<< "Input  value d. :" ;
cin >> n ;

for
(z=t ; z<x ; z+=n) ;

v = sqrt(((2*k)*t)/m) ;

cout<< " value of v after the loop using n as loop spacing "  ;

cout<< v <<endl ;
```

have I used the wrong loop or am I missing some key part to the code and if I have just missed a previous topic would it be possible to link it to me thank you in advance

Comment: Why is there a `;` after the loop. If you meant to include `v = sqrt(((2*k)*t)/m) ;` in the scope of the loop remove the `;`

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong.

That should be

```
for (z=t ; z<x ; z+=n)
{
    v = sqrt(((2*k)*t)/m) ;
}
```

or possibly

```
for (z=t ; z<x ; z+=n)
    v = sqrt(((2*k)*t)/m) ;
```

but I personally recommend against this as it leads to mistakes like what you did.

When you put a `;` on the same line as the for loop you are telling it to execute an empty code block (i.e. do nothing in the loop).